# How to efficiently insert a byte slice in a file?

Tags: performance, file, go

I am building a simple key-value store for fun. Right now, I am looking for an efficient way to insert a slice in a file.

My current approach:

- find the desired offset
- store in a buffer the blocks that precede the desired insert point
- append the byte slice to that buffer
- append the rest of the file
- Write to disk

Problem is:

- It is not a given that the whole file can fit in memory
- It is inefficient

I have looked into available libraries and sadly the best match I have found `os.WriteAt` overwrites the following blocks. Example:

```
import "os"

func main() {
    pathToFile := "./tmp"
    bufferToWrite := []byte{255, 255, 255, 255, 255}

    f, _ := os.OpenFile(pathToFile, os.O_CREATE|os.O_RDWR, os.PermMode)
    defer f.Close()
    f.Write(bufferToWrite)
```

So, at this point the content of `tmp` will be (after `$: xxd -g 1 -b tmp`):

> 11111111 11111111 11111111 (x) 11111111 11111111

Let's try to insert something with offset = 3 (x):

```
    bufferToInsert := []byte{0, 0}
    f.WriteAt(bufferToInsert, 3)
}
```

Output will be:

> 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000

And I want it to be:

> 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111

Any ideas?

Comment: It's much easier (and often safer and more efficient) to write a new file then replace the old one, rather than try to insert data and shift the entire rest of the file.

Comment: I am a little worried about frequently creating new files every time a user desires to insert a new (key, value) or update an existing one because I think it would increase the latency of those operations too much. Though I am not expert, I understand that I/O on disk are best kept to a minimum?

Comment: The problem is the concept of "inserting" values into a file -- there is no insert operation for a regular file. Any "insert" you do will have rewrite  50% of the file on average, and you will lose data if you error out during that rewrite. If you need to frequently insert things at random points in your storage, you're likely looking for some sort of database.

Comment: @JimB Thank you - that's exactly what I am trying to do (build a database). That's just for fun, though it is not supposed to ever become production ready; it is just to learn.

Comment: Then you need to start with some data structures that are used for database storage. Btrees, index files, etc.

Comment: @JimB I have dived into the internals of LevelDB a bit and that's the strategy I plan to follow later on (implement my own LSM-Tree) but I would like to get a first decent version working before I move onto implementing more complex DS. Thank you for your input! (:

Comment: Look into mmap and family. That's the usual way to project memory into files and what many KV stores and databases use.

Comment: @thwd Thank you I will look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inventing your own file format, you could copy the pack file format from Git.

The basic idea is to have an *index* file and a *data* file. When you want to insert a slice you just append it to the data file. Then you update the index file, which is usually smaller. Note that the pack file is not designed for real-time updates, but accompanied by individual object files.

Or have a look at the Berkeley DB file format.

Comment: Thank you Roland, I will look into that. And I will set your answer in a couple - leaving it open now so people can still post their suggestions. Right now what I am thinking is to have an index file as follow: [index: 4 bytes][offset: 2 bytes] where `offset` is the position of the entry in another file. It is much better than having to deal with the values as well. What do you think?

Comment: Forgot this bit: I want to later allow users to provide a comparator function according to which they can order their `key:value`. For now `index` will just be a `uint32` that I compute based on the binary representation of the corresponding value.

Comment: Your data structures depend on how large the keys and values can be. For the values, I would generally reserve 32 bits, and for the offsets 64 bits. But then, the overall size of such an index entry should be a power of two, so I would choose `{offset uint64; size uint32; reserved uint32}`.

Comment: @ErwanAaron: there are countless publications and courses that cover these things. It might be good to do some research before making random attempts at creating a database format, as this is a very broad subject.

Comment: @JimB I can't ask questions about design or good practices to an academic paper. If you don't want to answer that's fine but as you said, this is such a broad topic... I don't see what harm is done by asking for advice to far more experienced and knowledgable people. The goal isn't to build the next MySQL. Just for me to learn and get more experience working with low-level I/O.

Comment: @RolandIllig Would it be "bad design" to allow for an unlimited size for the keys? I could just add a field size that would tell me that the next size bytes are those of the key. Thank you Roland!

Comment: @ErwanAaron In the case of something like SQL-based databases, you usually have a way to specify the order like MySQL's `ORDER BY` condition to specify which field to sort data along with a sort direction, but the comparison function is predefined (for performance reasons). Later you might add your comparison functionality, but I'd keep it as simple as you can for right now.

Comment: As for the size of the keys, that depends on the data type of the key. Naturally types with fixed sizes such as uint64 would perform better in the general case, but nothing stops you from using, for example, a variable-length string as a primary key or a component in a composite key. There's also the question of what you mean by "key" since [more than one field can be a key technically](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/what_is_a_key.html).